# InfluxDB failed to start as a service

Tags: database, systemd, systemctl

I'm trying to configure InfluxDB for Automatic start-up on a RHEL7 machine.

if I do:

```
sudo systemctl start influxdb
```

the service fails

```
[dadmin@localhost dashboard]$ sudo systemctl start influxdb
[sudo] password for dadmin: 
[dadmin@localhost dashboard]$ sudo systemctl status influxdb
● influxdb.service - InfluxDB is an open-source, distributed, time series database
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/influxdb.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
  Drop-In: /etc/systemd/system/influxdb.service.d
           └─override.conf
   Active: failed (Result: start-limit) since Thu 2017-05-11 13:16:29 CEST; 10s ago
     Docs: https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/
  Process: 2562 ExecStart=/usr/bin/influxd -config /dashboard/influxdb.conf ${INFLUXD_OPTS} (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
 Main PID: 2562 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

May 11 13:16:29 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: influxdb.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
May 11 13:16:29 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Unit influxdb.service entered failed state.
May 11 13:16:29 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: influxdb.service failed.
May 11 13:16:29 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: influxdb.service holdoff time over, scheduling restart.
May 11 13:16:29 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: start request repeated too quickly for influxdb.service
May 11 13:16:29 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Failed to start InfluxDB is an open-source, distributed, time series database.
May 11 13:16:29 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Unit influxdb.service entered failed state.
May 11 13:16:29 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: influxdb.service failed.
```

This is the unit file:

```
[dadmin@localhost dashboard]$ sudo systemctl cat influxdb.service
[sudo] password for dadmin: 
# /usr/lib/systemd/system/influxdb.service
# If you modify this, please also make sure to edit init.sh

[Unit]
Description=InfluxDB is an open-source, distributed, time series database
Documentation=https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/
After=network-online.target

[Service]
User=influxdb
Group=influxdb
LimitNOFILE=65536
EnvironmentFile=-/etc/default/influxdb
ExecStart=/usr/bin/influxd -config /etc/influxdb/influxdb.conf ${INFLUXD_OPTS}
KillMode=control-group
Restart=on-failure

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
Alias=influxd.service

# /etc/systemd/system/influxdb.service.d/override.conf
[Service]
ExecStart=
ExecStart=/usr/bin/influxd -config /dashboard/influxdb.conf ${INFLUXD_OPTS}
```

But if I execute directly

```
/usr/bin/influxd -config /dashboard/influxdb.conf
```

InfluxDB start smoothly.

Where am I wrong?

Comment: See [this relevant thread](https://community.influxdata.com/t/cant-start-systemd-service-for-influxdb-because-of-tls-certs/2539) on the InfluxData community forums.

Comment: Hi Davide, just a question: why is present `-` in the assignment of `EnvironmentFile=-/etc/default/influxdb` ?

Comment: Hi Kyrol, the prefix "-"  indicates that if the file does not exist, it will not be read and no error or warning message is logged. See https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.exec.html

Answer (score 5):

I found the problem:

```
[dadmin@localhost dashboard]$ sudo tail /var/log/messages
May 11 16:21:41 localhost influxd: [I] 2017-05-11T14:21:41Z Using data dir: /dashboard/influxdb/data service=store
May 11 16:21:41 localhost influxd: run: open server: open tsdb store: open /dashboard/influxdb/data/_internal: permission denied
May 11 16:21:41 localhost systemd: influxdb.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
May 11 16:21:41 localhost systemd: Unit influxdb.service entered failed state.
May 11 16:21:41 localhost systemd: influxdb.service failed.
May 11 16:21:41 localhost systemd: influxdb.service holdoff time over, scheduling restart.
May 11 16:21:41 localhost systemd: start request repeated too quickly for influxdb.service
May 11 16:21:41 localhost systemd: Failed to start InfluxDB is an open-source, distributed, time series database.
May 11 16:21:41 localhost systemd: Unit influxdb.service entered failed state.
May 11 16:21:41 localhost systemd: influxdb.service failed.
```

When I had executed

```
/usr/bin/influxd -config /dashboard/influxdb.conf
```

The folders had been created with dadmin as owner

I removed the folders and restarted the service. Now all works fine.

Comment: Why does `sudo tail /var/log/messages` not work for me?

Answer (score 2):

The config script does not have permissions.

It references directories. When you run /opt/influxdb/influxd config > /etc/opt/influxdb/influxdb.conf the outputted config file puts all the directories under ~. When you are root, ~ translates to /root.

If you don't want to use /root as your InfluxDB data directory there are a few options.

Run /opt/influxdb/influxd config > /etc/opt/influxdb/influxdb.conf as the user you want to run influxd. Then the config file will use that user's home directory as the install location.
Explicitly edit /etc/opt/influxdb/influxdb.conf to reference the directories you want to use.

Also check this [blog](https://caffinc.github.io/2015/12/influxdb-service-ubuntu/) this might clear it out for you

Answer (score 1):

you can change the user and the group to root

```
[dadmin@localhost dashboard]$ sudo systemctl cat influxdb.service
[sudo] password for dadmin: 
# /usr/lib/systemd/system/influxdb.service
# If you modify this, please also make sure to edit init.sh

[Unit]
Description=InfluxDB is an open-source, distributed, time series database
Documentation=https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/
After=network-online.target

[Service]
User=root
Group=root
LimitNOFILE=65536
EnvironmentFile=-/etc/default/influxdb
ExecStart=/usr/bin/influxd -config /etc/influxdb/influxdb.conf ${INFLUXD_OPTS}
KillMode=control-group
Restart=on-failure

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
Alias=influxd.service

# /etc/systemd/system/influxdb.service.d/override.conf
[Service]
ExecStart=
ExecStart=/usr/bin/influxd -config /dashboard/influxdb.conf ${INFLUXD_OPTS}
```